# Unpermitted parameters with devise invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise, simple-form, devise-invitable

Here's a quick run down of my models

A **user** has many **sections**

A **section** has many **users**

users and sections are related through an object called **user_sections**

I'm using devise invitable to invite users to my rails app. I want to decide what sections belong to any user before I invite them.

Here is what I have in my `invitations_controller`. I can confirm that the **accept_invitation** sanitizer works, however the **invite** sanitizer isn't working as expected.

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: [:section_ids])
end
```

I added this input to `invitations#new`. The input is showing up and I can select which sections a user will have before I send the invitation and create the user.

```
<div class='form-inputs'>
  <%= f.association :sections %>
</div>
```

However, I'm getting this error in my logs:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :section_ids
```

And when I check in the rails console, the new user I invited has no sections associated with it even though I selected the sections in the form. It's because of this unpermitted parameter. However, when you look at the code in my invitations_controller, you can see that I am indeed permitting that parameter.

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: How have you verified that `accept_invitation` works if the `invite` does not work?

Comment: @MarkMerritt I have verified it because the parameters are indeed being permitted. After the fills in the first_name and last_name inputs and accepts the invitation, they are both saved.

Comment: @AngelGarcia This is a shot in the dark for me, but did you resolve this issue? I am experiencing this exact same problem.

Comment: @DanRubio hey! This was almost 3 years ago, so I don’t exactly remember. But I think I did solve it, and it was just naming issue. But I can’t remember for sure. Sorry I couldn’t be much help, hope you can solve it soon!